# Twig check if there are any values in the array

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How can I check if any values are provided to the array. In PHP I'm adding to the array like this:

```
$myArray['index1'] = $someVal1;
$myArray['index2'] = $someVal2;
```

The problem is that when in Twig I use |length filter it gives results when $someVal1 or $someVal2 have no values (these are values taken from the form so they don't have to be filled). So I want to check if the values are not provided in the whole array, so:

```
{% if myArray|what_filter_here? == 0|empty|whatever %} This text should not appear {% endif %}
```

Can it be done in one single condition?

Answer (score 29):

Something like:

```
{% if myArray|length > 0 %}
    This text should not appear 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 22):

Try with `empty` -

```
{% if myArray is empty %} ... {% endif %}
```

Comment: this is  a better answer because length depends on the passed object implementing the countable interface, hence the above seems to be more robust.